# Confirmation needed of the fact that subcategory $\mathbf{Lat}$ is not full in $\mathbf{Pos}$

Tags: category-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

If you are familiar with this stuff then you probably don't need the information
I have added. So let me start with the question:

> Can you prove that category $\mathbf{Lat}$
> is not a full subcategory of category $\mathbf{Pos}$?

I dived into the theory of universal algebras and encountered lattices.
I noticed that a lattice $\left(L,\wedge,\vee\right)$ can be desribed
as a poset that is equipped with binary products and coproducts. Here
$a\leq b$ is defined by $a=a\wedge b$. Then $a\sqcap b=a\wedge b$
and $a\sqcup b=a\vee b$. There is a category $\mathbf{Lat}$ having
lattices as objects and functions that respect $\wedge$ and $\vee$
as arrows. These functions are order-preserving which makes them arrows
in $\mathbf{Pos}$ having posets as objects and orderpreserving functions
as arrows. So $\mathbf{Lat}$ is a subcategory of $\mathbf{Pos}$
but I 'know' that it is not a full subcategory. As a confirmation
of that I am looking for an arrow in $\hom_{\mathbf{Pos}}\left(L,L'\right)$
that is not an arrow in $\hom_{\mathbf{Lat}}\left(L,L'\right)$. Here $L$ and $L'$ are lattices. So it is about a function that is orderpreserving, but does not respect (at least one
of) the operations $\wedge,\vee$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{matrix}
& & D & & & & & & D
\\ & \nearrow & & \nwarrow & & & & \nearrow & & \nwarrow
\\ B & & & & C & \quad \Longrightarrow \quad & B & & & & C & 
\\ & \nwarrow & & \nearrow & & &  & \nwarrow & & \nearrow
\\ & & A & & & & & & E
\\ & &  & & & & & & \uparrow
\\ & &  & & & & & & A
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: $A=B\sqcap C$ and $fA\neq fB\sqcap fC=E$ right? Thank you.